# How many batteries will be working after 280 minutes?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

> A study of data collected at a company manufacturing flashlight
>   batteries shows that a batch of 8000 batteries have a mean life of 250
>   minutes with a standard deviation of 20 minutes. Assuming a Normal
>   Distribution, estimate:
>
> How many batteries will continue working after 285 minutes?

This is my answer to this question does it look correct or are there any improvements I can make?

```
Batch: 8000
Mean: 250 minutes 
SD: 20 minutes


(285-250)/20 = 1.75
Z-Score of 1.75 = .4599
(.5-4599)*8000 = 320.8 batteries will be working
```

Comment: Effectively same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445203/a-normal-distribution-question-is-this-the-correct-way-of-going-about-it. So you could have just added it there instead of asking a new question.

Comment: Its actually not the same question and one question  per post!!!

Comment: @StubbornAtom gives a reference to a problem that uses the same method with different numbers.

Comment: @BruceET It was asked by Liam also, definitely a dupe

Answer (score 1):

Using R software in which `pnorm` is a normal CDF.
Lifetime $X$ of any one battery has $X  \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 250,\sigma=20).$ As you say, you need $8000\,P(X>285).$

```
8000*(1 - pnorm(285, 250, 20))
[1] 320.4733
```

Round to integer 320.

Standardizing and using printed tables of the standard normal CDF.

$$P(X > 285) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} >
\frac{285 - 250}{20}\right)\\ = P(Z > 1.75) \approx 0.0400.$$

Then .04(8000) = 320.

*Note:* Using R you get more decimal places of accuracy than the usual four place accuracy of printed tables.
I think the problem has been 'rigged' to give you an
integer answer from printed tables.

You have the right idea, but you could give a little clearer explanation of your method.

Comment: @ BruceET: Thanks I am doing a computer science course, I am no mathematician so the formulas are bit less complicated. So is the way I am doing it enough to get the correct marks? (If I rounded down to 320)

Comment: @ BruceET: Also I my Casio calculator gives the exact answer 320.8 so would I not round to 321?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea, but perhaps your presentation could be improved.

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the life of a battery, in minutes.

$\because X$ follows a normal distribution

$\therefore X \sim N(250,20^2)$

Find $P(X > 285)$, that is, the probability of a single battery lasting more than 285 minutes.

Can you take it from here?